# __call() method explanation

Tags: php, methods, magic-methods

I have this portion of code:

```
class FTPClient
{
    public function __construct() {
        $args_num=func_num_args();
        echo $args_num;
        $this->{"__construct".($args_num===0 ? '' : $args_num)}(func_get_args());
    }

    function __call($name,$args) {
        echo $name,count($args),'<br/>';
    }

    public function open() {
        echo 'open';
    }
}
    $o = new FTPClient('127.0.0.1','user','pass');
    $o = new FTPClient();
    $o = new FTPClient('127.0.0.1','user');
    $o->close();
```

the output looks like this:

```
3__construct31
01__construct11 //Don't understand how this output came together?!
2__construct21
close0
```

Would someone be so kind and could explain me the second line of this output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. #### First example

   ```
   $o = new FTPClient('127.0.0.1','user','pass');
   ```

   You have 3 arguments, means 3 gets printed with this line:

   ```
   $args_num = func_num_args();
   echo $args_num;  //output: 3
   ```

   After that you are trying to call the method `__construct3()`:

   ```
   $this->__construct3(func_get_args());
   ```

   Which is not accessible, means `__call()` gets called. In that magic method you print the name, here **`__construct3`** and the count of the arguments, here the argument array, means **`1`**.

   Output:

   ```
   3__construct31
   ```
2. #### Second example

   ```
   $o = new FTPClient();
   ```

   You have 0 arguments, means 0 gets printed with this line:

   ```
   $args_num = func_num_args();
   echo $args_num;  //output: 0
   ```

   After that you are trying to call the method `__construct()`, the constructor:

   ```
   $this->__construct(func_get_args());
   ```

   And the constructor is callable, so `__call()` won't get called here. Instead the constructor gets called again, but with an array, which holds the array of arguments, here an empty array.

   Now in the second call you have 1 argument, means 1 gets printed with this line:

   ```
   $args_num = func_num_args();
   echo $args_num;  //output: 1
   ```

   After that you are trying to call the method `__construct1()`:

   ```
   $this->__construct1(func_get_args());
   ```

   Now `__construct1()` is not accessible, means `__call()` gets triggered. In that magic method you print the name, here **`__construct1`** and the count of the arguments, here an array with the argument array, means **`1`**.

   Output:

   ```
   01__construct11
   ```

**Notes:**

- [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods) gets triggered, when you are trying to call an inaccessible method.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine, it's cleaner.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Have I noted what pain it is with the formatting, when you use a numbered list in an answer?! :]

Comment: Yeah, and you need to use 8 spaces instead of 4 to get a code block, but the editor doesn't realize that so you need to add those spaces manually~

Answer (score 2):

When you run the constructor with zero arguments, the constructor itself is called again. As the constructor is a valid method, the __call will not be invoked that time around (but will be later on, when you call __construct1).

You see the 01 because the 0 is printed by the constructor the first time around, which then calls `__construct([empty array])`, which prints the 1. It then calls __construct1 because there was an argument (the empty array of func_get_args()) - thus printing 1__construct1 (which then prints 1).

Perhaps you were meant, instead, to pass the arguments to the constructor directly, rather than in an array?

You will find this makes more sense if you print out more information - such as what method is doing the printing - and printing a newline after `$args_num`. That would have made this answer seem a much less confusing!

Answer (score 1):

Your second line is:

```
$o = new FTPClient();
```

That runs `__construct()` with 0 arguments, thus printing `0`.

Then, it generates a function name to call with:

```
"__construct".($args_num===0 ? '' : $args_num)
```

You ran the function with 0 args, so this just becomes `__construct`.  Since this function *exists*, it doesn't trigger the `__call` function.  You then call `__construct` passing it `func_get_args()` (which returns you an empty array).

Then `__construct` runs *again* with 1 parameter (an empty array), thus printing `1`.

You then generate the function name `__construct1`, which when called triggers `__call`.  You call `__construct1` passing it `func_get_args()`, which is an array containing one element, the empty array from before.

P.S. `count($args)` is *always* 1 because, you are doing:

```
$this->{"__construct".($args_num===0 ? '' : $args_num)}(func_get_args());
```

This calls the function and passes it *one* parameter.  An array.

If you want to *expand* that array and pass each element as its own paramter, then you need to use `call_user_func_array`.

```
call_user_func_array([$this, "__construct".($args_num===0 ? '' : $args_num)], func_get_args());
```